# Unit test failing in Intellij 13 but passes via command line

Tags: unit-testing, grails, intellij-idea, spock, intellij-13

I have a very simple unit test that test a controller action that renders the current user as JSON. Here is my test class:

```
@TestFor(UserController)
class UserControllerSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
        def springSecurityService = mockFor(SpringSecurityService)
        springSecurityService.demand.getCurrentUser { -> [name: "Jim"] }
        controller.springSecurityService = springSecurityService.createMock()
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test current"() {
        when:
        request.method = 'GET'
        controller.current()

        then:
        response.json.name == "Jim"
    }
}
```

Here is the controller (omitted non related code)

```
def springSecurityService

static responseFormats = ['json']

static allowedMethods = [current: "GET"]

def current() {
    respond(springSecurityService.currentUser)
}
```

I am executing this test alone via `grails test -unit package.class` and it works via the command line:

```
|Running 1 unit test... 1 of 1
|Completed 1 unit test, 0 failed in 0m 11s
.
|Tests PASSED - view reports in ...\target\test-reports
```

This does not work via IntelliJ because `springSecurityService.currentUser` is always null. Here is the resulting exception:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: Error parsing JSON
    at grails.converters.JSON.parse(JSON.java:292)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.testing.AbstractGrailsMockHttpServletResponse.getJson(AbstractGrailsMockHttpServletResponse.groovy:97)
    at massemailsystem.UserControllerSpec.test current(UserControllerSpec.groovy:28)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONException: Missing value. at character 0 of 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:470)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:357)
    at grails.converters.JSON.parse(JSON.java:283)
    ... 2 more
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In your setup, you configure `getCurrentUser`, but your code invokes `currentUser`. Unless there is something happening under the hood here, this could be a potential culprit.

Comment: @Lilshieste In groovy, `getCurrentUser` is invoked from `currentUser`

Answer (score 1):

You need to run this test case as grails test case in IntelliJ.  [image] [image]